# Google Script App change color cells when a cell have a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color

I've been trying to look for what I need to do but I couldn't figure it out how to do this from the previous posts I found.

I have this Google Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwmLLjvSfgNb0YD8sptdrjV_5N6tcleiO4q6j2gyQVM/edit#gid=593280854)

Want I' love to do is to analize the data in the sheet called "actual" and set the background color of the cells when it meets a condition. So basically, I'm looking for a script to do this:

```
get the data from the sheet called 'actual'
if a cell is error (equals to "#N/A") then set the color font to white
if a cell equals to "wnd" then set the background color to "red"
if the cell equals to "otc", then set the background color to "green"
etc..
```

It's going to have around 50 conditions and that is why I would love to do this with code instead of regular Conditional Formatting.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to minimize the use of get calls. Those are slow calls. So you want to take one big one. Then work with all the data. Here's some example code:

**Note** This function checks for values of 3 and sets them red background with white text. The current range its working with is defined in var range. Set that up yourself to whatever you need.

```
function setCellColors() {
  //Get the sheet you want to work with. 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Grab the entire Range, and grab whatever values you need from it. EX: rangevalues
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:E17");
 var rangevalues = range.getValues();
  //Loops through range results
 for (var i in rangevalues) {
  for (var j in rangevalues) {
   //Get the x,y location of the current cell.
      var x = parseInt(j, 10) + 1;
      var y = parseInt(i, 10) + 1;
   //Set the rules logic
     if (rangevalues[i][j] == 3) {
        //Set the cell background
        sheet.getRange(y,x).setBackground("red");
        sheet.getRange(y,x).setFontColor("white");
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good. Can you please explain me why you are using 10 as your second argument in these vars:      var x = parseInt(j, 10) + 1;    var y = parseInt(i, 10) + 1;

Comment: I've used your code to do this and I have updated the var range to do what I need. However, I only get the result until column O. I have updated the google spreadsheet that using as an example with this code so you can take a look at it. I just can't figure it out why is only working until column O. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 10 is the base of the numbers you're parsing to. if you wanted binary it would be different, or hexadecimal numbers, ect.   To update the spreadsheet to include more columns, change the range variable. You can either have this display dynamically, or statically. If you want it static, just pick the values like i did. If you want it dynamically, then you'll have to write it in. (please remember to choose an answer if it helped, this way future searchers can find this more easily)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  Having it statically works for me. The thing is that I've picked the values that I need for my range, but for some reason that I just can't get it, it doesn't work within the whole range, it stops at column O (although I have set the variable like this: var range = sheet.getRange("A1:DP15");

Comment: Do you have empty cells randomly in your sheet? Try rangevalues.length during the i and j loops and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I have empty cells randomly. Ok, cool, I will use rangevalues.lenght. Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this helps.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)

```
function setCellColors() {
//Get the sheet you want to work with. 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    // determine how how big your data range will be
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    // iterate through the data. 
for (var column = 1; column < lastColumn; column++) {
    for (var row = 1; row < lastRow; row++) {
        var cellget = sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue();
        var cellset = sheet.getRange(row, column);
        //Set the rules logic
        if (cellget === "#N/A") {
            //Set the cell background
            cellset.setBackground("red");
            cellset.setFontColor("white");


        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It does help! Thanks you very much.

Comment: When running the code, I get this execution hint: Method Range.getValue is heavily used by the script.Collapse
File: Code Line: 11
The script uses a method which is considered expensive. Each invocation generates a time consuming call to a remote server. That may have critical impact on the execution time of the script, especially on large data. If performance is an issue for the script, you should consider using another method, e.g. Range.getValues(). I'm not sure how to use the Range.getValues() method instead.

Comment: When the number of rows to evaluate grows, I'm getting this message: Exceeded maximum execution time.